# Three Images in one fabric js Canvas, clear and update a specific image

Tags: angularjs, fabricjs

I have a fabric canvas.

In HTML

```
<canvas id="template-editor-canvas" width="585" height="460"></canvas>
```

In SCRIPT

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('template-editor-canvas', {
    selectionColor: 'red',
    selectionLineWidth: 2
});

$scope.updateOnNgClickOne = function () {
    fabric.Image.fromURL("imageOne.png", function(img) {
                        canvas.add(img).renderAll();
                      }, {
                            width: 167,
                            height: 74,
                            left: 2,
                            top: 2,
                            angle: 0,
                            hasBorders: false,
                            hasControls: false,
                            hasRotatingPoint: false,
                            lockMovementX: false,
                            lockMovementY: false
                         });
};

$scope.updateOnNgClickTwo = function () {
    fabric.Image.fromURL("imageTwo.png", function(img) {
                        canvas.add(img).renderAll();
                      }, {
                            width: 167,
                            height: 74,
                            left: 2,
                            top: 200,
                            angle: 0,
                            hasBorders: false,
                            hasControls: false,
                            hasRotatingPoint: false,
                            lockMovementX: false,
                            lockMovementY: false
                         });
};

$scope.updateOnNgClickThree = function () {
    fabric.Image.fromURL("imageThree.png", function(img) {
                        canvas.add(img).renderAll();
                      }, {
                            width: 167,
                            height: 74,
                            left: 2,
                            top: 400,
                            angle: 0,
                            hasBorders: false,
                            hasControls: false,
                            hasRotatingPoint: false,
                            lockMovementX: false,
                            lockMovementY: false
                         });
};
```

The issue is whenever I click, new image object added each and every time on top of the existing. If I try to clear before render( canvas.clear() ), the entire canvas is getting cleared.

What I need is when I am clicking to update ImageOne, that particular image has to be removed and re-rendered.

I am expecting like below. It is possible other than this ImageFromUrl method.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var rect = new fabric.Rect();
canvas.add(rect); // add object
canvas.remove(rect); // remove previously-added fabric.Rect
```

Comment: Yes that is what is supposed to happen according to your code. In order to have the functionlaity you are expecting you need to implement a logic that deletes the existing image and then recreates is. and canvas.clear() is supposed to clear the complete canvas. If you can create a demo for your issue can help you better.